# Let chapter number be distinct in mainmatter and ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I would like the chapter number to be different in mainmatter and ToC.

In the ToC I would like to see :

```
chapter 1 ...
    bla bla bla


chapter 2 ...
    bla bla bla
```

But if I did :

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{chapter \arabic{chapter}}
```

In the text, when I do a crossref to a figure, for example, the figure number is `chapter 1.3` for figure 3. And I do not like that.

I tried to use `titletoc` package without success.

Here is a short example :

```
\documentclass{book}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{Serie \arabic{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\textrm{\Roman{section}}}

\title{titre}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\filcenter\sffamily} 
{\textit{\LARGE\@title}\\
\vspace{5mm}
{\Large\thechapter}
}%
{1pc}%
{\titlerule\vspace{1pc}\Huge}%
[\vspace{1pc}\titlerule\thispagestyle{plain}]

\RequirePackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{chapter}[1cm]{\vspace*{2ex}}{\bfseries\contentslabel{3em} : }{}    {\hfill\bfseries\contentspage}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Rappels}
\section{Section}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering\fbox{A figure}
\caption{A caption} 
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hline
aaa & bbb & ccc \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{A caption} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I would like to keep the "serie" in the ToC but not in the figure and table number.

Here is a solution which work without the babel package following the answer of gonzalo medina. I redefined `\chaptername` instead of manually add "serie" because all of this is in a class file and it is easier to change the name of the "serie" if it is defined from a variable.

```
\documentclass{book}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Serie}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\newlength\mylen
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\bfseries \chaptername~}
\settowidth\mylen{\bfseries\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum}
\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\mylen}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{:}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\textrm{\Roman{section}}}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\filcenter\sffamily} 
{\textit{\LARGE\@title}\\\vspace{5mm}
{\Large\chaptername~\thechapter}}%
{1pc}{\titlerule\vspace{1pc}\Huge}%
[\vspace{1pc}\titlerule\thispagestyle{plain}]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Rappels}
\section{Section}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering\fbox{A figure}
\caption{A caption} 
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hline
aaa & bbb & ccc \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{A caption} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

If I use the `\babel` package with the `francais` option, `\chaptername` is defined by babel at the beginning of the document. Thus I have to add this in the preamble :

```
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Serie}}
```

But it does not work for the ToC. In the ToC there is still chapter instead of "serie". Thus I defined a new variable and I use it instead of chapter name.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\newcommand{\seriename}{Serie}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\newlength\mylen
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\bfseries \seriename~}
\settowidth\mylen{\bfseries\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum}
\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\mylen}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{:}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\textrm{\Roman{section}}}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\filcenter\sffamily} 
{\textit{\LARGE\@title}\\\vspace{5mm}
{\Large\seriename~\thechapter}}%
{1pc}{\titlerule\vspace{1pc}\Huge}%
[\vspace{1pc}\titlerule\thispagestyle{plain}]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Rappels}
\section{Section}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering\fbox{A figure}
\caption{A caption} 
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hline
aaa & bbb & ccc \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{A caption} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To redefine the formatting of the chapter entries you can use either the `tocloft` or the `titletoc` package; below there's an example with `tocloft` showing the modifications required to include "Serie" before the chapter numbers and a colon immediately after the chapter numbers:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\newlength\mylen
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\bfseries Serie~}
\settowidth\mylen{\bfseries\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum}
\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\mylen}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{:}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\textrm{\Roman{section}}}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\filcenter\sffamily} 
{\textit{\LARGE\@title}\\\vspace{5mm}
{\Large\thechapter}}%
{1pc}{\titlerule\vspace{1pc}\Huge}%
[\vspace{1pc}\titlerule\thispagestyle{plain}]

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test Section One One}
\section{Test Section One Two}
\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\section{Test Section Two One}
\section{Test Section Two Two}

\end{document}
```

[image]

After the edit to the original question, here's some code in which I used `\addto\captionsfrancais` to change `\chaptername` in the preamble:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newlength\mylen
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\bfseries\chaptername~}
\settowidth\mylen{\bfseries\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum}
\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\mylen}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{:}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\textrm{\Roman{section}}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\filcenter\sffamily} 
{\textit{\LARGE\@title}\\\vspace{5mm}
{\Large\chaptername~\thechapter}}%
{1pc}{\titlerule\vspace{1pc}\Huge}%
[\vspace{1pc}\titlerule\thispagestyle{plain}]

\addto\captionsfrancais{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Serie}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Rappels}
\section{Section}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering\fbox{A figure}
\caption{A caption} 
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hline
aaa & bbb & ccc \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{A caption} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This do the trick but it removes all the format of the ToC.

Comment: @Ger all you have to do is to add the `titles` option to tocloft. I updated my answer with the settings from your example.

Comment: Ok it works, but I changed `\chaptername` to serie and latex does not consider that. Actuallay, I do not understand why. If I add `AtBeginDocument` it works for the mainmater but the toc remains with chapter. I did all in a class file based on the book class. If I change `chaptername` directly in the tex file `AtBeginDocument` is not necessary. I fix this by using another variable which is not `chaptername`.

Comment: @Ger Did you see my updated answer? I changed `\chaptername` to Serie in `\cftchappresnum`. And I used your settings so if something is not working something else is going on in your docuemnt and you *need* to provide that information in your question.

Comment: Yes I saw. The origin of my issue is the `francais` option of the `babel` package which define at the beginning of the document the name of chapter.

Comment: @Ger Please add some code to your question showing this; without the actual code is almost impossible to see what's going on. For example, if I add `\usepackage[french]{babel}` to my code, I don't see any problems. Please edit your question and add a complete minimal document showing the problem mentioned.

Comment: I did what you said. Tell me if it sounds ok for you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4741/discussion-between-gonzalo-medina-and-ger)

Comment: @Ger plase follow the link in the previous comment; in the chat room we can discuss the problem more easily.

Comment: @Ger I added a new example code to my answer; no need to define `\seriename` or to use `\AtBeginDocument`; simply use `\addto\captionsfrancais` to do the redefinition of `\chaptername`. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 3):

The toc setting is defined by `\l@chapter` which in book is

```
\newcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
```

So you can redefine that and add `Chapter` at a suitable point (just before `#1` for example)

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand if you have some problem with the table of contents, but if what that you want is a simple numbering of tables and figures in a document class type `book` (the same for the entire document) this example is self-explanatory:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering\fbox{A figure}
\caption{A caption} 
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hline
aaa & bbb & ccc \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{A caption} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No I do not want to remove the chapter number but only the chapter name.

Comment: Then you cannot insert the word "Serie" redefining `\thechapter`, because `\thechapter` is the number of the chapter that must be referenced. Perhaps is better comment the line 2 of your MWE and try to insert this word in `\titleformat`.